# Node.js cluster failing instead of re-directing to other workers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue where I have two workers running through Node.js clustering, and I am using a for loop to send a large number of requests to the workers. The requests are only targeting one worker as the load isn't enough for the OS to require use of the second worker. However, when I kill the targeted worker (kill worker.pid), instead of having the second worker continue receiving the requests, all requests are stopped and the program with the for loop hangs and eventually fails/gets an exception.

I don't want to change the code on the client side, and can't figure out how to handle this on the server side.

Here is my server side code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if(cluster.isMaster){
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++)
        cluster.fork();

    cluster.on('online', function(worker){
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' alive');
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal){
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
        cluster.fork();
    });
}
else {
    /*Includes and global variables*/
    var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res){
        var headers = {};
        headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
        headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
        headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = true;
        headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept";
        res.writeHead(200, headers);

        console.log("test");
        res.end("Response sent");
    }).listen(8070);
}
```

Here is my client code:

```
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
        {
            payLoad = "{\"otoo\":{\"keyName"+i+"\":\"valueName"+i+"\"}}";
            System.out.println(payLoad);
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(payLoad);
            reqEntity.setContentType("application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest);

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                try {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                            inputStream);
                    while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        chunk = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        System.out.println(chunk);
                    }

                } catch (IOException ioException) {

                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {

                    httpPostRequest.abort();
                    runtimeException.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the exception:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 173.36.55.252:8070 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at CprWrite.main(CprWrite.java:48)
```

Comment: Idea, try adding an exit route `if (req.url === '/exit') { process.exit(); }` to see if it handles things right that way, or maybe a throw route (same but throw an error).  You can also look into handling the signal (http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events).

Comment: did `console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');` get logged?

Comment: The worker's death did get logged. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I am currently trying to handle the signals; I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: FYI the current version of cluster (in 0.10.x) is considered . . . bad. It's being shifted to round robin in 0.12.x which is better, but still it's more common to simply start up multiple node.js servers on different ports and then load balance.  (or just use one node.js server, you likely don't actually need more than one)

Comment: Trying to avoid the one server situation because of the single point of failure. Is there any technology you would recommend for load balancing node.js servers?

Comment: Popular choices include nginx, haproxy and node.js.  Make sure your load balancer can handle websockets if you want them (the ones I listed do on newish versions) The nice part of doing it with independent processes is that scaling across CPUs and scaling across servers (or even across datacenters) becomes the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into those.

Interesting result from trying to handle the signals. On the callback for process.on SIGTERM, I did a server.close on my server and added a print statement inside the callback of the server.close. If I kill the worker, the print statement is not executed until my for loop completes, which means the server is somehow still receiving requests even after calling server.close.

Comment: cluster is weird, it's the master that actually listens

Comment: Oh and take a look at pm2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2 it's the solution that should have come to my mind first because it's the one I've used the most.

Comment: pm2 load balancing is also not working. I'm starting to think it's the client code...

Comment: Note that [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering) is a data mining technique. You probably meant [tag:load-balancing] or a similar server related tag.